# Create shortcut for Konsole with stylesheet

Tags: linux, shortcuts, kde, kubuntu, konsole

I'm using Konsole, and i have this wonderful stylesheet that colors the active tab

```
>> cat ~/tab.qss
QTabBar::tab:selected, QTabBar::tab:hover {
    background: #99BDDA;
}
QTabBar::tab:selected {
    border-color: #33FF33;
    border-bottom-color: #C2C7CB; /* same as pane color */
}
```

so, i just open a Konsole with:

```
>> konsole --stylesheet ~/tab.qss
```

and it works great.

HOWEVER,

I want my icon on the panel to be associated with the above command, so i changed the command in the icon Setting -> Application -> Command to be `konsole --stylesheet ~/tab.qss` instead of just `konsole` but it doesn't work. when i click the icon it just opens the usual Konsole.

Am i doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are using a tilde for home a home directory shortcut, but the tilde is not expanded in this instance. Instead, you'll need to use the whole path: /home/mrtubis/tab.qss
Alternatively, you may be able to use the relative path (relative to your home directory) of just tab.qss

Answer (score 0):

BTW, this is my tab stylesheet with some garish colors to make it really easy to spot the active tab:

parcher@ot-virtbox:~$ cat bin/lib/tab.qss

```
QTabWidget::pane { /* The tab widget frame */
     border-top: 2px solid #C2C7CB;
     position: absolute;
     top: -0.5em;
 }

 QTabWidget::tab-bar {
     alignment: center;
 }

 /* Style the tab using the tab sub-control. Note that
     it reads QTabBar _not_ QTabWidget */
 QTabBar::tab {
     background: qlineargradient(x1: 0, y1: 0, x2: 0, y2: 1,
                                 stop: 0 #E1E1E1, stop: 0.4 #DDDDDD,
                                 stop: 0.5 #D8D8D8, stop: 1.0 #D3D3D3);
     border: 2px solid #C4C4C3;
     border-bottom-color: #C2C7CB; /* same as the pane color */
     border-top-left-radius: 4px;
     border-top-right-radius: 4px;
     min-width: 8ex;
     padding: 2px;
 }

 QTabBar::tab:selected, QTabBar::tab:hover {
     background: #EE4444;
 }

 QTabBar::tab:selected {
     border-color: #33FF33;
     border-bottom-color: #C2C7CB; /* same as pane color */
 }
```